# Linkedin - Sharing entity is not authorized to perform this action

Tags: linkedin-api

We are publishing linkedin shares via `v2/shares` endpoint and for 1 profile we are receiving following error:

status: 401
message: "Sharing entity is not authorized to perform this action: null"
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/community-management/shares/share-api

We are obtaining the token for this request with following scope
['r_liteprofile', 'mgw_w_media', 'rw_organization']
(which is working fine for other profiles).

Can you explain what exactly the error means? The microsoft.com/* page I pasted above says the token is not strong enough. But the token is obtained with the same code which is working for dozens of other LI profiles.

I will appreciate any insight on this. Thanks.

Comment: We have the exact same problem - `v2/shares` stopped working for only one profile (same error message) - Did you manage to solve it or find a workaround?

Comment: Unfortunately not. I guess this is calling for some explanation from LI support side.

Comment: Same problem here. Has anyone found a solution?

Comment: I found my problem: the user didn't have write privileges on her company page. When connecting the page with another user, she had no more problems sharing content.